# Check ComboBox (Xceed WPF Toolkit), How to get short name to display from database?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, combobox

This is my first post and I am a relative newbie regarding all things programming related. I hope you will be patient with me.  I have a WPF application I am working on.  My current issue is a Check ComboBox I am using.  When I make selections out of the list that is pulled from a sqlite database file, the full name of the selection is displayed.  I would like to change this and have a short name from the database appear in the ComboBox area while leaving the long descriptive name in the dropdown portion. I thought working with display and value member would help out, but have yet to get it working.  I can get one or the other by changing the column index reference to my sqlite db. The ComboBox is a multi-select item and it needs to update as selections are made or cleared. Below is the bit of code I have that populates the ComboBox.  I am unable to attach an image of the data due to low Rep numbers. Column 0 is the full descriptive name, Column 1 has the short name I am interested in displaying.

```
public void Fill_Modality()

        {
            SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
            try
            {
                sqliteCon.Open();
                string Query = "Select * from Modality_list";

                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);
                SQLiteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string modname = dr.GetString(0);
                    Modality_Select.Items.Add(modname);
                }

                dr.Close();
                sqliteCon.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
```

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Patrick

Addendum:  Thank you to the folks who replied to the above post.  In reviewing the suggestions provided, I have found that I didn't quite capture in detail what I was trying to accomplish.

When I click the drop down, the detailed description shows along side the checkboxes.  That part is fine, no issue here.  What I am looking to do is this:  When the checkboxes are selected, instead of the detailed description showing in a comma delimited string in the collapsed combobox control, I would like to display the short name in a comma delimited string.  The data is from a sqlite databasefile.  The table is 2 columns, 0 is the detailed description, 1 is the short name.

If nothing else, I think a textbox that could be filled with the short names as the long name counter part is selected in the combobox would be fine as well.  The overall goal is to have the short names available in a string for use elsewhere in the project without causing confusion by our abbreviations.

Comment: if you want to change the query to return the short name then 2 things either reference the short name in your dr.GetString(0) change that to the following `string modname = (string)dr["YourShortFieldName"];` or change the query to return the exact fields you need..

Comment: Not sure I understand completely but you said that column 0 is descriptive name and column 1 is short name. Your code is getting column 0 `dr.GetString(0);`, which is the descriptive name. Change it to `dr.GetString(1);`.

Answer (score 0):

Only select what you need from the database, unless your table is only two columns, I'd avoid the astrisk. Use something like:

```
SELECT short_name, long_name FROM Modality_list
```

Then while iterating through them `dr.GetString(0)` would be used to access the short_name field and `dr.GetString(1)` would be the long_name.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, how about this:  You make a class with properties for short name and long name, do this for each item and put them into an array while simultaneously (within the same loop) adding the long name into the combobox.  This way, they'll have the same index in their respective containers.  Then, create a selected index changed event for the combobox where it uses the index of the combobox, references that index of the array, pulls the short name, and changes the text of the combobox to match.